# IPSec VPN connectivity from Ubuntu to AWS

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, vpn, amazon-ec2, aws

I have configured the VPN gateway and related settings at AWS side. Now I have to connect to the vpn from my Ubuntu machine. I am using my android mobile phone to access internet into my laptop via hotspot. I have downloaded the generic vpn configurations from aws console which contain the IKE and IPSec(with preshared key) configuration for each tunnel. Can anyone help me setting up this VPN client thing at my Ubuntu laptop. Please let me know if any other details you need.

Thanks.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out?